# Using jQuery to hide/show table row for posting a reply

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, row, toggle

I am building a bulletin board system that we can post a message to and people can reply to the message.  I have posting a new message working fine, and for every new message, I use AJAX to create a new table row for each message:

```
<table id="content-table">
<tr>

  <th scope="col" class="messagetime"> <? echo $time; ?> </th>
  <th scope="col" class"message body"></th>
  <th scope="col" class="messagereply"><form method="GET" action="Rindex.php"><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"><button type="submit" style="border-style:none;" class="post-icon" /></form></th>

</tr>
</table>
```

In the last column, I have an image that they press that I would like jQuery to create a new table row below this one with fields for entering a reply message, which will post to that specific message.

I can currently get a new row for every message and hide/show all of them, but I am not able to figure out how to get the reply button to target the unique row to reply a message:

```
<table id="content-table">
<tr>

  <th scope="col" class="messagetime"> <? echo $time; ?> </th>
  <th scope="col" class"message body"></th>
  <th scope="col" class="messagereply"><form method="GET" action="Rindex.php"><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>"><button type="submit" style="border-style:none;" class="post-icon" /></form></th>

</tr>

<tr id="replyrow" class="replyrow">

 <th scope="col"></th>
 <th scope="col" class="replyrowcontent"> <Post Reply Form would be in here.> </th>
 <th scope="col"></th>

</tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestions?  I have a feeling there is going to be something involved with a parent/child relationship, but I conceptualize this in my head!

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use tables for layout.

Comment: Any recommendations?  You know it's funny.  See how stackoverflow has a hidden DIV that shows when you want to reply to a message?  I'm trying to go for something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div stlye="disply:none;" id="hidden">
    Hidden
</div>



<script>
$.ajax({
   /* ... other options here... */
   success: function (){
       $('#hidden').show();
   }
});
</script>
```

Now obviously you need a bit of research ... as well you can also use the `click()` method and put the ajax there, or something like that...

**Oops forgot to give you a link** 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

good luck, if you have more questions use the box below [comment] and I'll answer your questions if any

Comment: also look up `delay()`, and `queue()`, so you give it a delay after the success if you wish so it don't hide that quick, and maybe `fadeOut()` for an effect rather than just hidding it and showing it :)